# VPC Interface Endpoint is accessible from subnets which isn't associated with it

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint, aws-networking

I'm trying to access s3 using interface VPC Endpoint but i have a technical issue which i can’t solve.

I have A VPC with the following Subnet:

1. Subnet A (Private without Internet)
2. Subnet B (Private without Internet)
3. Subnet C (Public with Internet Gateway)
4. Subnet D (Private with NAT)

I have two instances:

1. i-01 (Subnet A)
2. i-02 (Subnet D)

I have an interface VPC Endpoint for Subnets A,B and Private DNS is Enabled.

the issue is when i dig the endpoint s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com in both instances it returns the VPC Endpoints IPs.

Expected Behavior:
Instance i-01 returns the VPC Endpoints IPs and instance i-02 return the public regional IP.

Am i understanding the interface concept wrong or the expected behavior is what should happen ?

and if i'm understanding it wrong how to seperate subnets from using the interface endpoint and the public IP

Comment: Note: this is related to the use of [Amazon-provided DNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#AmazonDNS) and [Private DNS](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/11/05/amazon-route-53-now-supports-private-dns-with-amazon-vpc/) in VPC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am i understanding the interface concept wrong or the expected behavior is what should happen ?

Yes, you have the concept wrong. Interface endpoints have **VPC-scope**, not subnet-scope. This means that all instances in a given VPC will use the interface endpoints, regardless of which subnets they are in.

To solve this, disable `Private DNS` and manually in the instance specify the endpoint of the interface for the instance which should use it.

Comment: Does the same goes for Gateway Endpoints are they VPC-scope too?

Comment: @ziadhassan No. Gateway endpoints have subnet-scope. So you can change interface endpoint to gateway endpoint if only S3 or Dynamodb are concerned.

Comment: @Marcin that isn't accurate.  Gateway endpoints have route table scope. If multiple subnets share a common VPC route table, then either all of the subnets associated with that route table -- or none of them -- will use a given gateway endpoint, depending on whether the endpoint has an entry in the relevant route table.